# Difference between <xsl:template match="/*"> and <xsl:template match="*">

Tags: xslt, match

can you explain me which is the difference between

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="*">
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

Look at the match rule :)

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second rule,

```
<xsl:template match="*">
```

matches any element anywhere, and sets the context node to that element.

It's the other ones (1 and 3) where the difference is subtle.  To understand the difference, you have to know about the concept of a "document root" node.  As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5957159/4525) states,

> The **root node** is the node that is the ancestor of all other nodes in
>   the XML document. It is not an element. ... Confusingly, the outermost
>   element is sometimes called the "root element."

With that in mind

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
```

matches only the "outermost element" in the document, and sets the context to that element, while

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

matches only the "document root" itself, and sets it as the context.  That rule will *always* match, even an empty document, whereas `/*` will only match documents that actually have an element.

So if you have a document

```
<A />
```

the first rule (matching `/*`) will match, and the context node will be `A`.

The third rule (matching `/`) will also match, but `A` will be a *child* of the context node.