# How to remove the first child of an XML node with XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

Data.xls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="Data" select="document('Data.xml')/*[1]"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="remove-first-child">
    <xsl:with-param name="Node" select="$Data"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="remove-first-child">
  <xsl:param name="Node"/>
  <xsl:element name="{name($Node)}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$Node/@* | $Node/*[position() > 1]"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- same as above, but for testing over 2 recursion levels -->
<xsl:template name="remove-first-child1">
  <xsl:param name="Node"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="remove-first-child">
    <xsl:with-param name="Node">
      <xsl:element name="{name($Node)}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$Node/@* | $Node/*[position() > 1]"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**How to remove the first child in Data and produce output that could be passed to remove-first-child again?**

When calling the first template I get:

```
$> msxsl Other.xml Data.xsl
<Alphabet>
  <B/>
  <C/>
  ...
</Alphabet>
```

When I change to call the second template I get:

```
$> msxsl Other.xml Data.xsl
Error occured while executing stylesheet 'Data.xsl'.
Code:  0x80004005
Reference to variable or parameter 'Node' must evaluate to a node list.
```

The desired result would be:

```
<Alphabet>
  <C/>
  ...
</Alphabet>
```

**Update: How I tried to apply the suggested solutions.**

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="remove-first-child">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="remove-first-child"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()[parent::*][not(preceding-sibling::*)]" mode="remove-first-child"/>

<xsl:template name="remove-first-child-a">
  <xsl:param name="Node"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$Node" mode="remove-first-child"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="remove-first-child-b">
  <xsl:param name="Node"/>
  <xsl:variable name="Temp">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$Node" mode="remove-first-child"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$Temp" mode="remove-first-child"/>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="remove-first-child-a">
  <!-- xsl:call-template name="remove-first-child-b" -->
    <xsl:with-param name="Node" select="$Data"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

But this also only yields the same results as mentioned above. `a`:

```
$> msxsl Other.xml Data.xsl
<Alphabet>
  <B/>
  <C/>
  ...
</Alphabet>
```

`b`:

```
$> msxsl Other.xml Data.xsl
Error occured while executing stylesheet 'Data.xsl'.
Code:  0x80004005
Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
-->$Temp<--
```

So I guess the key is the type system...

And as a general note: The main manipulation is happening for `Other.xml`, it's not just a dummy call. Some data is taken from `Data.xml` and it's to be processed before joined with `Other.xsl`. That processing consists only of the removal of the first child dependent on some conditions (not part of this question) which happen to be implemented recursively, because it's XSL. And along the recursions it might be necessary to remove several first children of the same and of different, traversed nodes.

Whata I'm trying to express in XSL here is a projection `node --> node`, removing the first child of the input node.

Comment: This `document('Data.xml')/*[1]` is actually selecting the root element. It's the same as `document('Data.xml')/*` since there is only one root. If you want to select the first child of the root element, you need: `document('Data.xml')/*/*[1]`.

Comment: It's producing the right result for "one recursion", i.e. calling `remove-first-child`, but it doesn't work for two recursions, i.e. calling `remove-first-child1`. How to create the right result in the first template that could be passed to it's own parameter `Node` again, to recursively delete the first child elements, i.e. of `<Alphabet>` in this example? Calling it with depth 3 or more should empty `<Alphabet><A/><B/><C/></Alphabet>`.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of recursion in XSLT (i.e., following the input document's structure), you want to use `apply-templates`, not `call-template`.  This avoids the issue you're getting (missing node set), since the template will only be applied to nodes that exist.

The following transform sets up a standard identity template, then adds an override that emits nothing for first children.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- Standard identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Skip first child -->
    <!-- the "parent" check is needed so that the root node is not skipped -->
    <xsl:template match="node()[parent::*][not(preceding-sibling::*)]" />

    <xsl:variable name="data-doc" select="document('Data.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$data-doc/*" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on a dummy document where the external file `Data.xml` contains the following sample input,

```
<A>
    <B1>
        <C1 />
        <C2 />
    </B1>
    <B2>
        <C1 />
        <C2 />
    </B2>
    <B3>
        <C1 />
        <C2>
            <D1 />
            <D2 />
        </C2>
        <C3>
            <D1 />
        </C3>
    </B3>
</A>
```

This gives the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A>
    <B2>
        <C2 />
    </B2>
    <B3>
        <C2>
            <D2 />
        </C2>
        <C3>
        </C3>
    </B3>
</A>
```

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to `xsl:apply-templates` to a `xsl:variable`, but I want to manipulate a "variable" here. The main processing is going on for `Other.xml`. My question is just the critical part.

Comment: @Max, did you try it?  You absolutely can `apply-templates` to a variable.  See edit -- the output is exactly the same.

Comment: I did, see my question for: "Update: How I tried to apply the suggested solutions."

Comment: @Max, I don't see where you set `$Refactorings`, but if you're operating directly on the result from `document()`, it's not going to work as you expect; you'd need to use `$Refactorings/*` instead to select the "root" element (this is the infamous ["root node/document node"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5957159/4525) confusion).

Comment: I'm sorry, it should say "$Data" not "$Refactorings". (I corrected it.) Though, I suspect `<xsl:variable name="Data" select="document('...')/*[1]"/>` to return one type (a node set?) in Data, while `<xsl:copy-of/>` or `<xsl:applytemplates/>` return another one. So `remove-first-child` is a projection `A (node-set?) --> B`. In this case it'd be no surprise cannot operate on it's own result. I don't know how to make it a proper projection `node --> node` (or `C --> C`), and use that on any node given in a variable or parameter.

Comment: @Max, If you want to operate on a projection (of more than one node) through a variable, you have to use the `node-set()` function, which is available as an extension in all the platforms that I've ever used.  But it's not clear from your question why you have to use a variable, or why you have to use `call-template`.  You can do `apply-templates` on sets from XPath, including those from external documents, without variables or extension functions.

Comment: it'd be totally sufficient to have a projection `node --> node` (not `nodes --> nodes`). I just was going along with a node set as long as it's transforming one node into a new one dropping its first child. I want to be able to target this projection at any given node of Data while recursing through it, and it's inserted to `Other.xml` at different stages. This "injection" is new. `Other.xml`'s processing is older and heavy already, though working. XSL breaks my head when when I see how difficult it is to get a `node --> node` projection done... :/ (Thanks for your help!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*//*[position()&lt;=1]"/>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And change the 1 by 2 if you want to filter both the first and second element (it works as explained in harpo's answer).